# Carbon in Laravel -- Call to a member function addDay() on integer

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, php-carbon

I'm trying to build a scheduler in which an incremental day addition and subtraction method is required.

Here, I am simply trying to add a day to this variable (which is displayed to the user elsewhere) each time this function is executed via a button I set up that routes to a certain location. But, I keep getting this error

> Call to a member function addDay() on integer

whenever I try to execute this. I am new to using the Carbon interface and looked through the documents, which led me to try parsing the function (worked when I had the same error with a string) but to no avail obviously. Any help is appreciated and/or a possible explanation of how this error is working really.

```
function addDay(){
$day = (int) Carbon::now()->format('j');
$day = $day->addDay();
}
```

Thanks in advance. If there is a better way to do this (adding days incrementally with the button/link), I would love to hear it. My logic seems flawed after working on the application the entire day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're casting the `Carbon` date object into an `integer` by using the `(int)` in the first `$day` variable. Therefor when you're trying to access the function `addDay()` it's failing, because `$day` is no longer a `Carbon` object but an `integer`.

```
$day = Carbon::now();
$day = $day->addDay()->format('j');
```

This should work, and if you need to cast it to an `integer` for some reason, then do it like this.

```
$day = Carbon::now();
$day = (int) $day->addDay()->format('j');
```

This way you cast the `integer` after you've added the day.

There is also a much cleaner approach to this syntax, which uses method chaining like so

```
$day = (int) Carbon::now()->addDay()->format('j');
```

Comment: Alright, cool. That looks like it solved that. But now I'm getting the error but instead of "on integer" it's "on string"

Comment: What is the desired returned value ?

Comment: It should just be increasing the integer value for day. So if today is the second (read '2'), when hitting the button, the value should read 3 instead of 2.

Comment: @guisbonddev I fixed the examples above, it was my mistake. You need to use the format function at the end, because it returns a `string` instead of the `Carbon` object. Also added an example of cleaner syntax.

Answer (score 1):

As @Classified said but a cleaner approach would be to work with Carbon object first and then apply format on that.

Like this:

`$dateObj = Carbon::now()->addDay();
$day = (int) $dateObj->format('j');`

Cleaner approach and better readability.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation on the above answer. But after fixing, I'm now getting the error but instead of "on integer" it's "on string"

Comment: Can you tell me which line generates an error? It's hard to reproduce the same error.

Comment: Its the `$day = $day->addDay();` line

Answer (score 1):

What is the desired returned value ?

```
$day = Carbon::now()->addDay();
return $day->dayOfWeek; //day of the week, 03/08/18 (now) returns 6 (INT)
return $day->format('j'); //day of the month, 03/08/18 (now) returns "4" (STRING)
return $day->day; //day of the month, 03/08/18 (now) returns 4 (INT)
return $day //Carbon object (at now() + 24h) that you can manipulate
```

Comment: This is more of a practical approach to my original question although another user had the actual answer. Is there a way to adjust this so that if I kept hitting the button it would continue to add days? Like if today is "2" then if I hit it twice it would read "4"?

Comment: Well if it's a frontend Ajax request, you'll need to save this value somewhere to "increment" it. In the session, Redis, Database... Then the ajax return the new date, and you can update frontend (momentJS  for date manipulation in JS, it's the JS's Carbon). Also a one liner `Carbon::now()->addDay()->day` would returned the desired INT.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the info. What's the easiest way to store it?

Comment: If it's user related, session can be used. Redis (or another key/value pair cache based) with a user related key would work. Database is slower, but would work. It really depends on your needs.

Comment: Alright, so I played around with some session stuff and stored the origional day (now value) like this `session(['previousDate' => $day]);`. But, when I tired to get it out and add a day `$var = session('previousDate')->addDay();` I get a "call to member function on string."

Comment: You need to store the Carbon object ($day) in the session variable. Then use it to output a INT or anything from it. But the session must remain a Carbon object that you can manipulate. Can you try dumping the session variable ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177362/discussion-between-guisbonddev-and-mtxz).

Answer (score 0):

You have to `addDay` to Carbon instance not to the integer (the day) :

```
$dt = Carbon::create(2012, 1, 31, 0);    // 2012-01-31 00:00:00
echo $dt->addDay();                      // 2012-03-04 00:00:00
```